# Can't run Java program in debug mode Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, debug-mode

When I run my program in Eclipse normally, it runs fine, but I want to run it in debug mode. When I attempt to do so, I get the error:

> *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't find transform methodID at JPLISAgent.c line: 558
> *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" at JPLISAgent.c line: 406

> Fatal error: processing of -javaagent failed"

It worked fine without me changing anything just days ago. The only difference is I've rebooted my computer since more than once. I even tried updating Eclipse, which did nothing, and running from command line. At first I got one error, but after updating Eclipse, I got another error instead:

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/402/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
> JVMJ9TI064E Agent initialization function Agent_OnLoad failed for library instrument, return code -1
> JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti29(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed

Any idea what could be going wrong or how I could fix it? I'm on MacOS 10.15.5 (Catalina) and using Java 8 (IBM Semeru)

Edit: For clarification, I have checked my Build Path and Compiler settings in Eclipse and they all match up.

Comment: Same error message here: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?articleId=129804

Comment: @howlger thanks! The solution there was to remove an extra space, however I do not have an extra space.

Comment: Please show the command line that is used by Eclipse for debugging: in _Run > Debug Configurations..._ in your launch configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that (the space might be added implicitly). Your Eclipse is up to date, right?